# Python API XML parsing - Namespaces

Tags: python, xml, api, xml-namespaces, tableau-api

I'm parsing some XML returned from my Tableau server via API using Python. Namespaces are involved, and I think I may be lacking some fundamental understanding of how they work. Here is what my XML looks like:

```
<tsResponse version-and-namespace-settings>
  <parent type="Project" id="1f2f3e4e-5d6d-7c8c-9b0b-1a2a3f4f5e6e" />
  <permissions>
    <workbook id="1a1b1c1d-2e2f-2a2b-3c3d-3e3f4a4b4c4d" name="Finance">
      <owner id="9f9e9d9c-8b8a-8f8e-7d7c-7b7a6f6d6e6d"/>
    </workbook>
    <granteeCapabilities>
      <group id="1a2b3c4d-5e6f-7a8b-9c0d-1e2f3a4b5c6d"/>
      <capabilities>
        <capability name="Read" mode="Allow"/>
        <capability name="Filter" mode="Allow"/>
        <capability name="ViewUnderlyingData" mode="Allow"/>
        <capability name="ExportImage" mode="Allow"/>
        <capability name="ExportData" mode="Allow"/>
        <capability name="AddComment" mode="Allow"/>
        <capability name="ViewComments" mode="Allow"/>
        <capability name="ShareView" mode="Allow"/>
      </capabilities>
    </granteeCapabilities>
  </permissions>
</tsResponse>
```

Here is the code I'm running, pared down to where the problem occurs. My aim is to initially identify each group id under a given workbook id, then find each capability under the group.

```
xmlns = {'t': 'http://tableau.com/api'}
test_response1 = []
test_response2 = []

url = "tableau.my.org/api/2.4/sites/siteid/workbooks/workbookid/permissions?pageSize=1000".format()
server_response_WB2 = requests.get(url, headers={'x-tableau-auth': auth_token})
test_response1.append(server_response_WB2.text)
server_response_WB2 = ET.fromstring(_encode_for_display(server_response_WB2.text))
permissions = server_response_WB2.findall('.//t:permissions', namespaces=xmlns)

for permission in permissions:
    capabilities = permission.findall('granteeCapabilities')
    test_response2.append(capabilities)

print test_response1
print test_response2
```

test_response1 contains a list like:

```
[[<Element '{http://tableau.com/api}permissions' at 0x3c07d70>], 
[<Element '{http://tableau.com/api}permissions' at 0x3bb8dd0>]]
```

test_response2 however, returns a list of empty lists:

```
[[], [], []]
```

In the code above, I'm looking for 'granteeCapabilities' as a tag. I've also tried looking for it as a path, using the namespace, like so:

```
capabilities = permission.findall('.//t:permissions/granteeCapabilities', namespaces=xmlns)
```

This returns the same result. A list of empty lists. Why am I able to find the data under permissions, but not at lower levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is likely has something to do with XML namespaces then you really should not omit the namespaces part of your XML form the question since it is fundamental for diagnosing the problem and for writing a working solution.

I suspect the namespace `http://tableau.com/api` was declared as a default namespaces (the one without prefix) in the XML, in which case all descendant elements without prefix implicitly inherit the same namespace from the ancestor. This would explain why `granteeCapabilities` didn't work for you, and you should try to add the prefix `t` here as well :

```
capabilities = permission.findall('t:granteeCapabilities', namespaces=xmlns)
```

If you don't need any information from `permissions`element, you can just get `granteeCapabilities` directly :

```
capabilities = root.findall('.//t:granteeCapabilities', namespaces=xmlns)
```

---

Here is a short but complete example demonstrating the solution :

```
raw = '''<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="tableau/com/api tableau.com/api/ts-api-2.4.xsd">
  <parent type="Project" id="1f2f3e4e-5d6d-7c8c-9b0b-1a2a3f4f5e6e" />
  <permissions>
    <granteeCapabilities>
      <group id="1a2b3c4d-5e6f-7a8b-9c0d-1e2f3a4b5c6d"/>
      <capabilities>
        ....
      </capabilities>
    </granteeCapabilities>
  </permissions>
</tsResponse>'''

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(raw)
xmlns = {'t': 'http://tableau.com/api'}
permissions = root.findall('.//t:permissions', namespaces=xmlns)
for permission in permissions:
    capabilities = permission.findall('t:granteeCapabilities', namespaces=xmlns)
    print capabilities
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/753908)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
[<Element '{http://tableau.com/api}granteeCapabilities' at 0x402f430c>]
```

Comment: I tried this form, but still am getting a list of empty lists. I take your point about the namespaces, but I don't know where to find that. I'm modifying example code provided by Tableau. Do you have any tips on how I might read the namespace from the XML using Python?

Comment: What is the actual XML string you received looks like? (especially this part `<tsResponse version-and-namespace-settings>`). Can't you just print or save to file the :  `_encode_for_display(server_response_WB2.text)` ?

Comment: The beginning reads: <tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns: xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau/com/api http://tableau.com/api/ts-api-2.4.xsd">  I tried navigating to those urls, but there's nothing there.

Comment: @JeremyReal namespace URI is just an identifier, not necessarily a real URL which you can navigate to. I just updated the code a bit, since you are already in `permission` element the XPath shouldn't mention `t:granteeCapabilities` directly. If this doesn't work, try `.//t:granteeCapabilities`.

Comment: @JeremyReal also the URL, according to your comment, should be `xmlns = {'t': 'tableau.com/api'}` (i.e without `http://`, or is that just a copy-paste problem?) ...

Comment: I did omit the http:// in the url, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Using .//t:granteeCapabilities directly worked. Thanks for your help! Could you edit the answer to reflect the update?